# Make Animation In web using HTML, JS,

Tags: javascript, html, json, animation

i'm looking for someone to describe me that how i can make such a animated cards , like in the link.I want to create ecards. i searched alot but i am still empty that HOW TO MAKE SUCH AN ANIMATED ECARD . 
i will be really thankful to you if someone helps me to figure it out.Thanks

please visit here : https://codecanyon.net/item/christmas-card-magic-lights/full_screen_preview/13721494?_ga=2.52809258.348819546.1516316033-509877775.1512146146

Here is another : https://ihatetomatoes.net/svg-christmas/

Answer (score 1):

CSS is capable of quite a bit. You might start there and then try something more complicated like Javascript and JSON if you need more. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-image: url(man1.gif);
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-image: url(man1.gif);}
    25%  {background-image: url(man2.gif);}
    50%  {background-image: url(man3.gif);}
    75%  {background-image: url(man4.gif);}
    100% {background-image: url(man5.gif);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This creates a 5 frame animation, but you can control the timing with the percents you choose. You can make images move across the screen, change size, repeat etc. If you combine multiple animations together you could get some pretty nice looking effects.

I recommend checking out w3schools.com as a starting place. I use that site all the time (including to get some of the code above). Good Luck.
[w3schools - CSS Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Val Head's course on CSS animations:

https://www.lynda.com/CSS-tutorials/CSS-Animation/439683-2.html

She covers everything from the basics, through traditional frame animations up to complex cutting edge stuff. It helped me a lot.

You can probably do that plus a few other courses within the free trial limit on Lynda